# Replying to mails on a non-default mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have many mailboxes in Outlook. I have set-up the following code to process incoming mails on one of my non-default mailboxes (requests@address.com).

I want to process all mails arriving in this box, perform an action on the content, then ReplyAll to that mail.

The problem is that the ReplyAll only includes the mailbox itself as a recipient (requests@address.com) and not the sender. The result is that the sender does not get a response but that the box keeps sending and receiving by itself in a loop.
If there is more than one person cc'd in the original, they get a copy of the mail but not the sender himself.

When using ReplyAll, how can I get the mailbox to identify the sender as the recipient instead of the mailbox itself?

```vb
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olRecip As Recipient

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olRecip = olNs.CreateRecipient("requests@address.com")  '// Owner's Name or email address
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecip, olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Debug.Print Item.Subject
        Dim myReply As Outlook.MailItem

        Set myReply = Item.ReplyAll
        myReply.htmlbody = "Replied At: "& Now()
        myReply.SentOnBehalfOfName = "requests@address.com"
        myReply.Send
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Let know if you still having issue

Comment: Thanks Om3r, I followed the tip below where I removed the box itself if it was a recipient (else endless loop) and added the item.SendEmailAddress if it was excluded. This proved to be a workable solution. I couldn't find a more elegant solution nor do I know why this behaviour arises... still trying to refine.. Thanks for your help, especially on the non-default mailbox listener :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the sender is included in myReply, you could add Item.SenderEmailAddress to the myReply.To.

You could exit if Item.SenderEmailAddress is "requests@address.com".

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why the box adds itself when I use the reply options but I implemented this and now it replies to all recipients excluding itself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Recip As Recipient

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then

        Debug.Print Item.Subject

        Set Item = Item.ReplyAll
        Set Recip = olReply.Recipients.Add Item.SenderEmailAddress
            Recip.Type = olTo

        Item.HTMLBody = "Replied At: " & Now()
        Item.display
    End If

End Sub
```